# Showing that $(A-y)\cap E=A\cap (E+y)$

Tags: real-analysis

When I think about $(A-y)\cap E=A\cap (E+y)$ geometrically, it seems clear that this is true. "Shift $A$ to the left $y$ units and intersect it with $E$" or "Shift $E$ to the right $y$ units and intersect it with $A$. Geometrically, these seem the same.

However, I'd like a more formal method showing that they are equal. I tried the usual, letting $x\in(A-y)\cap E$ which means that $x\in A-y$ and $x\in E$, or equivalently, $x=a-y$ for some $a\in A$ and $x\in E$. But I seem to be stuck on showing how this implies that $x$ is also in $A\cap(E+y)$, showing that $(A-y)\cap E\subset A\cap(E+y)$.

Hmmm.... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

$(A-y)\cap E=\{x\in E:x+y\in A\}$, and $A\cap(E+y)=\{x\in A:x-y\in E\}$. Thus, $(A-y)\cap E$ is a subset of $E$, and $A\cap(E+y)$ is a subset of $A$; there’s no reason to think that they are the same set. Take $E=(0,1)$, $A=(1,2)$, and $y=1$: then $(A-y)\cap E=(0,1)$, and $A\cap(E+y)=(1,2)$. These are clearly not the same set.

$A\cap(E+y)$ is the set of points in $A$ that end up in $E$ when you translate them $y$ units to the left; $(A-y)\cap E$, on the other hand, is the set of points in $E$ that end up in $A$ when you translate them $y$ units to the right. If you think about this for a bit, you’ll see that

$$\Big((A-y)\cap E)\Big)+y=\Big(A\cap(E+y)\Big)\;.$$

That is, the two sets are not equal, but they are translates of each other.